# How to build a static version of cocos2d-x and link it to my project

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

Firstly, I'm using `Cocos2d-x v3.6` for Win32 desktop + `Visual studio 2013` and `C++`.

When building Cocos2d-x, always it has been built as a dynamic version not a static version as I want.

- **How to build it as static version ?**
- **Then, How to bind it with the project ?**

Comment: Well, this is mostly a general VC question rather than specific GameDev one. Anyway, you just have to mark cocos2d-x project output type as static library, and add that project, to your game's references.

Comment: @Ali.S: Thanks, but I'm have already done it by selecting `multi-threaded(/MT)` instead of `multi-threaded DLL(/MD)` from `C/C++ -> Code Generation`, and when bind the `cocos2d-x` with my project I find that my project has been compiled as dynamic version. Please If possible to give me the steps to compile `Cocos2d-x` to static version.

Comment: Actually that was not the problem (change it back to multi-threaded dll). You should have changed "configuration properties->General->Project defaults->Configuration type" to "static library (.lib)". Then in your game's project properties, in "common properties->references" add cocos2d as a reference

Comment: @Ali.S: Thanks for help, but there is something wrong about linking when compiling my project. Note that `cocos2d-x` itself separate from my project, in the sense that `cocos2d-x` was compiled previously, and my project compiled separately. I have created a screenshot for the problem [ [screenshot](http://picpaste.com/pics/2015-06-13_192925.1434219004.jpg) ].

Comment: the easiest way to do it, is creating a solution containing both your project and cocos2dx. if you insist on keeping them separated, you should first compile cocos2dx, and generate ".lib" file. then in your game project properties, linking, additional libraries, add that lib file.

Comment: @Ali.S: This is exactly what I did, compile `cocos2d-x` separately, then link the `.lib` with my project. but there are many errors appeared after compiling, and this is a [ [screenshot](http://picpaste.com/pics/2015-06-13_192925.1434219004.jpg) ] for these errors.

Comment: That means you are not linking things properly... but seriously, comments are not for chatting, if you can't get it done, take a trip to [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development), there are plenty of people there who can solve your problem